# Django & Python: Creating a Timetable

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use Django to create a timetable. I have tried to realise it with Python, it looks like:

```
durations = [30, 30, 45] #lessons with various durations
count=0
start_time = 9
for x in durations:
    count = count + x/60
    end_time = count + start_time
    print(end_time)
```

Output：

```
9.5   # 09:30
10.0  # 10:00
10.75 # 10.45
```

My Django template:

```
    {% for student in students %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
        <td>{{ student.first_name }}&nbsp;{{ student.last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ student.duration }} mins</td>

        <! Stuck here: start time and end time ––> 
        <td>Start Time - End Time</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

My goal is getting a table like this:

```
Student A | 30 mins | 09:00 - 09:30
Student B | 30 mins | 09:30 - 10:00
Student C | 45 mins | 10:00 - 10:45
```

There are filters to do mathematical operations such as "add" and "sub", but seems we can't do something like "x = x + 1"?

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you store `duration` in django? are they integers?

Comment: Ok. I think the best way here is to use a _custom_ template tag; if you add the code related to your `Student` model, I can help you with that.

Comment: @PedramParsian Thanks for your help, I have just got [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59682425/django-python-keep-working-on-creating-a-timetable) about this timetable. Wondering if you would like to have a look of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing calculations in template, you should do that in view. Here is a pythonic solution that can be used(see the code comments for explanation):

```
# view

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def your_view(request):
    students = list(Student.objects.all()) # DB hit once only
    count=0
    start_time = datetime.now().replace(hour=9,second=0,microsecond=0,minute=0)  # getting start time at 9 am
    for s in students:  # no more DB hits as query is already evaluated
        s.start = start_time.strftime('%H:%M')  # using strftime to get string from datetime object
        start_time += timedelta(minutes=s.duration)  # adding timedelta of duration to increase start time
        s.end = start_time.strftime('%H:%M')
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'students':students})

# template

{% for student in students %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
        <td>{{ student.first_name }}&nbsp;{{ student.last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ student.duration }} mins</td>
        <td>{{ student.start }} - {{ student.end }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am now trying to add several rests (fixed time, e.g. 12:00 to 12:30 & 14:00 to 14:45). I am thinking to make few more "for loops" outside of "for s in students", but I guess you must have a smarter solution? I will edit my question for the details. Thanks again!

Comment: it would be better if you asked a new question :) . Also, If you want me to look at that question, then please put a reference in the comment section below :) .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help on the "views.py". Wondering if you would like to have a look of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59682425/django-python-keep-working-on-creating-a-timetable)?